# MYSQL - JOIN the 1 table or the other table depending if there is a match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table called `events` and I am doing a select on this table to display a grid with the select results.

The `events` table has a column called `s_code`. The `s_code` value comes from either the `suppliers` or `members` table.

How would I do a single `JOIN` that checks the `suppliers` and `members` table to get the code's name without having to do a `LEFT JOIN` on both `members` and `suppliers` tables like my query below. Basically I only want to have `b.s_name` where I have both `b.s_name` and `c.s_name` at the moment.

```
SELECT a.s_id, b.s_name, c.s_name, a.s_date, 
       a.s_description, d.s_name, a.s_actiondate,    
       e.s_name, a.s_emailed, a.s_status 
  FROM events AS a 
     LEFT JOIN members   AS b ON a.s_code = b.s_code 
     LEFT JOIN suppliers AS c ON a.s_code = c.s_code 
     LEFT JOIN webuser   AS d ON a.s_userid = d.s_ai 
     LEFT JOIN webuser   AS e ON a.s_actionuserid = e.s_ai 
 WHERE a.s_status = 'A' 
   AND a.s_userid = '1' 
   AND a.s_transactionstatus = 'A'
```

Comment: when you say 'where I have both b.s_name and c.s_name' is different of the title which one you want? when the name is on both or when it is on one or another?

Comment: The name will only be in one or the other. I want to do a single join that looks at members to get the name and if there is no match, then it must look in suppliers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [coalesce](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) the two columns into one, if the first is non null return that, otherwise the second;

```
SELECT a.s_id, COALESCE(b.s_name, c.s_name) s_name, a.s_date, ...
```